# Server-side requests and XmlHTTPRequest (client-side) and security

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I was wondering about the following:

When I make an `XmlHTTPrequest` to a external source outside my domain it will fail when there is a conflict with the `same-origin-policy`. This is due to security reasons. The code I wrote will be executed on a client's PC, which has restrictions.

However when I use a PHP script and access the external source with `curl` or `file_get_contents` my server is allowed to do this. I could output the external source to my site using an `XmlHTTPRequest`.

So with *PHP* or *ASPX* as intermediary I can output sources to my site that I cannot access with an `XmlHTTPRequest`.

- Why is this "work-around" via the server allowed, it looks to me like the same security risks could apply?
- Which other security concerns are there with an `XmlHTTPRequest`?

Obviously one would not allow such a request to load files from the file system of the user. But you can circumnavigate the `same-origin-policy` blockade with a server request for external sources, like from `example.com\file.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When my browser makes a request to a website it includes a lot of information about me (such as my ip address and any cookies I have for that website) that can be used for authentication.

If you were to use XMLHttpRequest to make a request to another site, it would be as if I had visited it myself. If the data in the response was made available to your JavaScript then you would have access to (for instance) my webmail, my social networking profile, my online banking and the company intranet on the LAN that I'm connected to.

A request from your server is coming from you, not me. You wouldn't have my ip address / cookies / etc. The site wouldn't give you any of the data that is private between it and me.

Comment: Well that's entirely true, you could make a deal with an affiliate and send user data to third parties unnoticed. Thanks!

Comment: @Mouser — There are still three parties involved. You. The user. The other site. If you want data that is secret between the user and the other site then you have to get one of them to trust you (and making the other site an affiliate of yours is one way to do that) and give you the data. You don't have that by default. The Same Origin Policy prevents that data from leaking to you without that trust.